# Facebook insights API - Popular Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, facebook-insights

I have a domain that I currently have insights setup for where I can view details at facebook.com/insights . My problem is that I would like to use the facebook API to access the Popular Pages listed under the 'Like Button' menu. On the documentation for insights, I can't find anything that will return popular links ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ ). Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Are you able to access facebook.com/insights? This page is blank for me for days. Only the header and footer, no content,